Current for Anderson-type model in linear response
I would like to raise an issue regarding calculation of current for Anderson-type model as discussed in the corrected version (14 January 2016) of the book "Many-body Quantum Theory
in Condensed Matter Physics, an introduction" by HENRIK BRUUS and KARSTEN FLENSBERG, chapter 10.
The system is composed of a quantum dot attached to two left and right leads symmetrically. Using the even and odd combination of the leads 'states, the Hamiltonian of the system simplifies into a form including two separate parts:
1- a quantum dot attached to the even combination of the leads and
2- odd combination of the leads.
The parts 1 and 2 are independent and with a clever manipulation, the current operator turns into the form (Eq. (10.47)):
$$I=\frac{-i}{\sqrt{|t_L|^2+|t_R|^2} }\sum_{\nu_o \sigma}(t_L t_R c_{\nu_o \sigma}^{\dagger}c_{d\sigma}-t_L^*t_R^*c_{d\sigma}^{\dagger}c_{\nu_o \sigma}),$$
where $t_L$ and $t_R$ are tunnelling amplitudes from dot to the left and right leads, respectively, $c_{d\sigma}$ annihilation operator of the dot orbital d with spin $\sigma$, and $c_{\nu_o \sigma}$  the annihilation operator of the state $\nu_o$ of the odd combination of the lead states.
Now my question:
The dot and even combination of leads' states are independent in the Hamiltonian and there is no tunnelling between them, but the current is defined as tunnelling between them! How is it possible to have a non-zero current?
Any help is appreciated.
